# This looks like an attempt to reply to the flaggers

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

Moderators sometimes try to communicate with the flagging community by taking a slightly different approach so our flags get either disputed or declined.

I'm not sure what the moderator (who should remain nameless) tried to communicate here:

[image: Timeline with delete, lock and undelete events.]

Here is the [actual answer](//stackoverflow.com/posts/65390845/timeline) [(screenshot for those <10K)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc0wA.png).

Can we get some elaboration from a  (the?) moderator on what we should learn from this. I'm asking because I gave wrong advice to some of our regulars in SOCVR and I feel sorry/guilty about that. Please talk to my pitchfork...

Comment: Nameless mod by the name ..... :D

Comment: Your torch and pitchfork rights are hereby revoked until next year:)

Comment: Your pitchfork is very disappointed in you, rene

Comment: My guess would be that a moderator incorrectly declined the spam flags, realized their mistake, disputed the spam flags, and then went ahead to nuke the post as spam. So, the error in declining the flags was corrected by changing the status to disputed (best we can do). I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: From the post history I can see this looks like one of those "ooops... didn't mean that button *oh beep* - I'll correct it as best as the system allows" (one I've certainly been guilty of a couple of times). I'm going to say it's a case of "mod declines a flag", "mod goes oops - ahh - I might have not got that one right", a mod can only 'clear flags' marked as R/A - marking them all as disputed and it also undeletes/unlocks the post in doing so (hence its history)... the "unnamed" mod then also cast their own spam flag on the post and destroyed the account.

Comment: A moderator! Poke him with the forks!

Comment: I'll enforce what @Cody said here... don't worry 'bout it :)

Comment: @JonClements You'll *"enforce"* it? As in "Don't worry about it, or else",... Or you'll reinforce it?

Comment: @Nick I suspect "endorse" was intended. :)

Comment: What the undeleted history removed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8047628/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)?

Comment: @AnnZen No, the history of answers has never been shown in the question timeline.